# link_to the current page plus/merged with a param

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

A bit of a softball question, but my Google Fu escapes me at the moment.

How do I link to the current page but then specify params to be merged into the query string?

For instance, if the current page is `/resources`, I want to be able to specify something like `current_page_plus(:param => 'attribute')` that evaluates out to `/resources?param=attribute`.

This would hopefully also merge with existing attributes, so if the current page was `/resources?a=b&c=d`, then `current_page_plus(:c => 'e')` would evaluate to `/resources?a=b&c=e`.

Comment: I've managed to hamfist `link_to "My link", params.merge(:c => 'e')`, but I have a feeling there's a better way to do this.

Comment: Similar but for internal parameters like `a/:id/b`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2543576/rails-link-to-current-page-and-passing-parameters-to-it

Answer (score 75):

You can use `url_for` passing the params.

```
url_for(params.merge(:c => "e"))
```

If you use an helper like `link_to` that internally uses `url_for` you can skip the `url_for` and pass the has directly.

```
link_to "Page", params.merge(:c => "e")
```

Comment: If I want to pass in an anchor, which would normally go as an option to the _path or _url method, how would I do that?

Comment: If you want to pass in an anchor, it would look something like this `link_to "Top", params.merge(c: "e", anchor: "top")`