# Is it safe to accept URL parameters for populating the `url_for` method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using Ruby on Rails 4.1.1 and I am thinking to accept parameters (through URL query strings) that are passed directly to the `url_for` method, this way:

```
# URL in the browser
http://www.myapp.com?redirect_to[controller]=users&redirect_to[action]=show&redirect_to[id]=1

# Controller
...
redirect_to url_for(params[:redirect_to].merge(:only_path => true))
```

Adopting the above approach users can be redirected after performing an action. However, I think people can enter arbitrary`params` that can lead to security issues...

Is it safe to accept URL parameters for populating the `url_for` method? What are pitfalls? What can happen in the worst case?

---

By logging `params` during requests to my application I noted Rails adds *always* `:controller` and `action` parameters. Maybe that confirms `url_for` can be used the above way since it is protected internally and works as-like Rails is intended to.

Comment: What do you mean with "sure"?

Comment: @Yan Foto - With "sure" I mean that no attacker can break things in the application (phishing, for security reasons, any other unknown to me pitfall).

Comment: I assume you meant to ask if it is "safe to accept URL parameters for...". It is common to accept the URL to redirect to as a parameter in the URL, but you must validate the parameter on the server side (like you would any other data provided by the user.)

Comment: I get it! I think secure would be more suitable

Comment: @Hector Correa - You are right: the word is "safe" not "sure" (I updated the question). Are `params` internally validated for correctness by the `url_for` method? What could happen with "malicious" `params`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This it is safe internally as Ruby On Rails will only be issuing a [HTTP redirect response](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_redirection#HTTP_status_codes_3xx).

As you are using `only_path` this will protect you from an [Open redirect](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Open_redirect) vulnerability. This is where an email is sent by an attacker containing a link in the following format (say your site is `example.com`).

```
https://example.com?foo=bar&bar=foo&redirect=http://evil.com
```

As the user checks the URL and sees it is on the `example.com` domain they beleive it is safe so click the link. However, if there's an open redirect then the user ends up on `evil.com` which could ask for their `example.com` password without the user noticing.

Redirecting to a relative path only on your site fixes any vulnerability.

In your case you are giving users control of your controller, action and parameters. As long as your GET methods are [safe](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#page-22) (i.e. no side-effects), an attacker could not use this by creating a crafted link that the user opens.

In summary, from the information provided I don't see any risk from phishing URLs to your application.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However I have a concerning doubt: is it good to give users control of controllers, actions and parameters?

Comment: @Backo: They already have "control" with their browser. They can type _anything they want_ after `https://www.example.com`.

Answer (score 0):

Rails [`redirect_to`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Redirecting.html#method-i-redirect_to) sets the HTTP status code to [`302 Found`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302) which tells the browser to [`GET`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods) the new path as you defined it by `url_for`. `GET` is a considered a [safe method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Safe_methods) in contrast to

> ... methods such as POST, PUT, DELETE and PATCH [which] are intended for
>   actions that may cause side effects either on the server, or external
>   side effects ...

The only problem *would have been* if someone could gain access to methods such as `create` and `destroy`. Since these methods use HTTP methods other than `GET` (respectively `POST` and `DELETE`) it should be no problem.

Another danger here is if you go beyond CRUD methods of REST and have a custom method which responses to `GET` *and* changes the database state:

**routes.rb**

```
resources something do
  member do
    get :my_action
  end
end
```

**SomethingController**

```
def my_action
  # delte some records
end
```

**For future ref:**

Rails has a number of [security measurements](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html) which may also interest you.

Comment: I will use `url_for(params[:redirect_to].merge(:only_path => true))` just for GET requests so it should not be a not good idea, as you said. But, other than that, what could be pitfalls with "malicious" `params`?

Comment: The problem is your server side. You pass the variables per `GET` but you don't check them on your server side. What if someone decides to give `redirect_to[action]=delete`?

Comment: The malicious attacker that sends `redirect_to[action]=delete` should trim a HTTP request with the DELETE verb in order to really delete the record. I just use `url_for` the above way for GET requests so any problem should not arise.

Comment: That is true. I just checked it. `redirect_to` redirects the browser and the browser only uses `GET`. I will update the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you confirm that *The only problem would be if someone gains access to methods such as `create` and `destroy`*, so that no problems arises for any input parameter? I am interested more on the security of `params` to be passed to the `url_for` method.

Comment: I will rephrase I think I have too much nested sentences.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70242/discussion-between-yan-foto-and-backo).

Comment: ... you mentioned *Another danger* in your answer... what is the first danger?

Comment: The paragraph before. But that really shouldnt happen

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly an answer, just wanted to point out that you shouldn't use something like

```
url_for(params)
```

because one could pass `host` and `port` as params and thus the url could lead to another site and it can get worse if it gets cached or something.

Don't know if it threatens anything, but hey, it's worth pointing out

Comment: Yes, it threatens things. Don't do this without a whitelist or `only_path: true`.